# How to trigger button selection over cell selection in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accordion

**Situation:**
So I have a set of `DLradiobuttons` inside a custom `tableViewCell`. The table expands when I click the label(ex. UseVisuals or visual schedule) and shows the options below. After I expand a row, the buttons should be allowed to be clicked, but rather the cell itself is clicked and highlighted.

**Issue:**
Is there a way to prioritize `radiobutton` selection over the cell selection?

I created the cells programmatically but the buttons are created in the storyboard. Could it be causing the issue? Should I implement the buttons programmatically as well?

**Screen Image is as below**

[image]

Comment: pls add your storyboard image for this VC.

Comment: Just use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none` inside your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

To stop cell selection do

**1. By code**

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

**2. By storyboard**

Select your tableView and change the property **Selection** as below

[image]

Comment: I tried this but this disables both cell selection and button selection. How can I enable button selection from then?

Comment: it does not disable button selection.

Comment: `btn.isEnabled = true` <--- do this. and make sure you not falsed it anywhere in the code

Comment: It does not disable the buttons, but I think the cell view covers up(?) the buttons and the buttons become non clickable or non interactable.

Comment: Buttons are not directly clickable on the storyboard as well. While other buttons can be clicked on the storyboard

Comment: @ChrisKim changing the selection style to none doesnt mean it disables the button. Probably there is something different issue. I done same thing many times. So suggests you to add your code work.